# cannot play VTC video file (.mov) using VLC player

Tags: vlc, codecs, mov

I have a training course contains .mov files which have video codec as apple graphics smc.

I have googled and found out to add these options to play them
[link from where I got help](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1736690&page=3)

But they are playing fine only in SMplayer. I want to configure similarly and play those files in VLC player.

This is the error which I'm facing

```
Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.

[0xb0d03d20] blend blend error: no matching alpha blending routine (chroma: RGBA -> RGBP)
[0xb0d03d20] main blend error: blending RGBA to RGBP failed
```

It is repeating...

Thanks for any help...

Comment: try playing the files in terminal like `vlc <path to file>`  what error do you get?

Comment: @Ashu, Thanks for the reply. I forgot to mention that I've already installed mplayer, w32codecs from medibuntu as well

Comment: Posted in the question. Also installed ubuntu restricted extras

Comment: Generally speaking, since Ubuntu got the restricted-extras meta-package, I began disregarding medibuntu.  If you need a custom spin of a specific app, compile it in a PPA and add that.  Otherwise, recently I've found medibuntu to be more painful than it's worth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget it guys. Even VLC player in windows is not playing the video. Only audio plays for those files. But KMplayer in windows plays them fine. I'll adjust with SMplayer in ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Just install [Medibuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Medibuntu) to play .mov files.

Comment: tried all sorts of stuff, kindly read the previous comments